# Can't find Microsoft One note in iPad's appstore

Tags: ios-appstore, ipados

I have iPad MM172LL/A, OS version 11.12 (15B202). I would like to install Microsoft One Note.
When I got to app store on the iPad and search for Microsoft One Note, it's not showing up. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What’s going on is your iPad doesn’t meet the minimum version, so the listing is likely suppressed. It also could be a country region restriction, but that’s harder for others to test for you. The simple reason is you didn’t purchase an older version of the app to re-download that and/or the developer removed the old version entirely.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-onenote/id410395246

[image]